# How to get localized values of OSGi bundle headers without a Bundle object

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle

If I have an `org.osgi.framework.Bundle` object, I can ask for its localized headers (like `Bundle-Name`) using [`Bundle.getHeaders(<locale>)`](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r6/core/org/osgi/framework/Bundle.html#getHeaders(java.lang.String)).

But does there exist a similar facility that I can use to get the values oflocalized headers (taking the `Bundle-Localization` header into account, if present) when I just have a `File`, `JarFile`, or `Manifest` object? Or do I have to implement the whole lookup procedure myself (as outlined in the OSGi spec)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That support is built into the OSGi framework. So if you are not asking the framework for the localized headers of a bundle, you will need to implement the specified rules yourself.